# typescript extend class with imported class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

If I extend a locally exported class, it works.

Working example:

```
export class classA {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

export class classB extends classA {

constructor() {
    super();

    this.do();
}

private do(): void {
    // do something
}
```

But when I import classA from outside of the file it's not work.

not Working example:

```
import { classA } from '../'; // I use index.ts file, so the reference is good.

export class classB extends classA {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.do();
    }

    private do(): void {
        // do something
    }
}
```

File structure:

```
Root/
- index.ts

- classA(folder)/
   - index.ts
   - classA.ts

- classB(folder)/
   - index.ts
   - classB.ts
```

The index.ts file inside classA folder:

```
export * from './classA';
```

The root index.ts file:

```
export * from './classB';
export * from './classA';
```

Error message:
class classB extends _1.classA 
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

I need to load outside from this file, because I would like to use classA in other files... Any idea why happen this?

**[Solved]**:
In the root index.ts file the order have to be:

```
export * from './classA';
export * from './classB';
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `../index.ts`? Are you exporting `class A` as `default`?

Comment: @rossipedia I updated the question with the file structure and the content of index.ts files

Comment: Why not reference classA directly in classB? import { classA } from '../classA/classA';

Comment: There are many folder in root, and it is simpler than write down the direct reference in every file. - But I take a try, may be this help me.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @Poku 2.3.2 - but I think i found the problem, the order of export in the root index.ts was bad, but i take another try.

Comment: Thank you guys, to help me to find the problem! I updated the question with the solution.

Comment: Do not put a solution in the question. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the root index.ts file the order have to be:

```
export * from './classA';
export * from './classB';
```

Answer (score 2):

Import classA directly. Try this:

```
import { classA } from '../classA/classA'; 
export class classB extends classA {

constructor() {
    super();

    this.do();
}

private do(): void {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I use index.ts file in that folder, and the file exported inside it.

Comment: then you should only use one ./ instead of ../. I changed my code.